# Adding every nth number in a list starting from n

Tags: python

I am trying to add every second number in a list, starting from the second number.

Here is what I have but it includes the first number:

```
def add(numbers):
    return sum(numbers[::2])
```

Comment: `sum(numbers[1::2])`

Comment: [Pythonic way to return list of every nth item in a larger list](//stackoverflow.com/q/1403674)

Comment: it does not *include* it, it starts from it and as a result, it *includes* all the numbers that you want to *exclude*.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the starting position to 1 (`1::2`) you get every even number of the list.

```py
def add(numbers):
    # 1::2 -> starting at 2nd with step 2
    numbers = numbers[1::2]
    print(numbers)
    return sum(numbers)

add([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

Output:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8]
20
```